# traceback when trying to set up the Michael Nielsen mnist network

Tags: python, mnist

I'm trying to set up a network for learning mnist digits as described by Michael Nielsen in his book (http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html#exercises_191892). However, when trying to import the mnist_loader into a Python3 shell, I get a traceback I can't make any sense of. Very greatful for any help!

```
>>> import mnist_loader
>>> training_data, validation_data, test_data = \
... mnist_loader.load_data_wrapper()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "/Users/xxx/Nielsen Network/src/mnist_loader.py", line 68, in load_data_wrapper
    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
  File "/Users/xxx/Nielsen Network/src/mnist_loader.py", line 43, in load_data
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = cpickle.load(f)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 614: ordinal not in range(128)
```

this ist the mnist_loader.py:

```
import _pickle as cpickle
import gzip

# Third-party libraries
import numpy as np

def load_data():
    """Return the MNIST data as a tuple containing the training data,
    the validation data, and the test data.

    The ``training_data`` is returned as a tuple with two entries.
    The first entry contains the actual training images.  This is a
    numpy ndarray with 50,000 entries.  Each entry is, in turn, a
    numpy ndarray with 784 values, representing the 28 * 28 = 784
    pixels in a single MNIST image.

    The second entry in the ``training_data`` tuple is a numpy ndarray
    containing 50,000 entries.  Those entries are just the digit
    values (0...9) for the corresponding images contained in the first
    entry of the tuple.

    The ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are similar, except
    each contains only 10,000 images.

    This is a nice data format, but for use in neural networks it's
    helpful to modify the format of the ``training_data`` a little.
    That's done in the wrapper function ``load_data_wrapper()``, see
    below.
    """

    f = gzip.open('../data/mnist.pkl.gz', 'rb')
    training_data, validation_data, test_data = cpickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def load_data_wrapper():
    """Return a tuple containing ``(training_data, validation_data,
    test_data)``. Based on ``load_data``, but the format is more
    convenient for use in our implementation of neural networks.

    In particular, ``training_data`` is a list containing 50,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  ``x`` is a 784-dimensional numpy.ndarray
    containing the input image.  ``y`` is a 10-dimensional
    numpy.ndarray representing the unit vector corresponding to the
    correct digit for ``x``.

    ``validation_data`` and ``test_data`` are lists containing 10,000
    2-tuples ``(x, y)``.  In each case, ``x`` is a 784-dimensional
    numpy.ndarry containing the input image, and ``y`` is the
    corresponding classification, i.e., the digit values (integers)
    corresponding to ``x``.

    Obviously, this means we're using slightly different formats for
    the training data and the validation / test data.  These formats
    turn out to be the most convenient for use in our neural network
    code."""

    tr_d, va_d, te_d = load_data()
    training_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in tr_d[0]]
    training_results = [vectorized_result(y) for y in tr_d[1]]
    training_data = zip(training_inputs, training_results)
    validation_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in va_d[0]]
    validation_data = zip(validation_inputs, va_d[1])
    test_inputs = [np.reshape(x, (784, 1)) for x in te_d[0]]
    test_data = zip(test_inputs, te_d[1])
    return (training_data, validation_data, test_data)

def vectorized_result(j):
    """Return a 10-dimensional unit vector with a 1.0 in the jth
    position and zeroes elsewhere.  This is used to convert a digit
    (0...9) into a corresponding desired output from the neural
    network."""
    e = np.zeros((10, 1))
    e[j] = 1.0
    return e
```

Comment: Please, edit the question with the `mnist_loader.py` sources as well so users have enough details to highlight exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're running Python 3 version. If I try it with Python3 I get the same error. As stated in the [README](https://github.com/mnielsen/neural-networks-and-deep-learning#code-samples-for-neural-networks-and-deep-learning) it only supports Python 2.6 or 2.7. If you cannot run it with Python 2 try this other repository below mentioned in the same README that supports Python 3

[MichalDanielDobrzanski/DeepLearningPython](https://github.com/MichalDanielDobrzanski/DeepLearningPython)